# Select com cast(numeric as decimal) funciona, mas criação de view não

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, cast

Bom dia a todos!

Eu trabalho atualmente com postgresql e estou fazendo uma migração de banco de dados, e preciso criar uma view das minhas tabelas do banco antigo. Pois bem, preciso que as colunas numéricas fiquem com arredondamento 15,3 mas estou encontrando um problema ao qual não consegui entender.

O select funciona:

```
select cast(15.2547 as decimal(15,3)) as quantidade_medida_estatistica
```

A criação da view não funciona:

```
create or replace view teste as select cast(15.2547 as decimal(15,3)) as quantidade_medida_estatistica
```

O erro retornado é:

> ERRO:  não pode mudar tipo de dado de coluna da visão "quantidade_medida_estatistica" de numeric(15,4) para numeric(15,3)

Agradeço toda ajuda!

Comment: Você está criando assim mesmo "chumbado" ? Se for isto faça com 15.254 ou 15.255 , nõ sendo isto (criando em coluna) tente com um round ..... cast round9.......,3) as ....

Comment: Obrigado @Motta ! Não seria chumbado mesmo não rs. Foi para exemplo apenas. A sua solução também funciona, mas um cara explicou o meu problema aqui [http://stackoverflow.com/a/39642666/5453988]. Básicamente o problema está em eu usar o create or replace view, onde nesse caso, se aplicaria um drop e create view. Obrigado!

Comment: Responda sua pergunta para não ficar em aberto. Somente ao ler tudo é que se sabe que já foi resolvido.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a solução e explicação, para meu problema na resposta deste tópico: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39642666/5453988 .

Basicamente, eu não posso realizar um CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW alterando o tipo de uma coluna. Para esses casos se faz necessário realizar um DROP view e em seguida um CREATE view.